# Block all future ActiveSync Devices?

Tags: exchange-2010, iphone, android, activesync

We're working on requiring MDM on all devices. I've got all current devices set up, but we're still open for users to add their device without MDM. How can I block ALL future devices without blocking the current? I want to make sure if they aren't explicitly approved, they cannot access email. But again, I don't want to block anyone already approved. Make sense?